# EDB. Is it possible to create multiple tables with db.create()?

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, datalogging

Good day! I seem to be having trouble creating multiple tables with EDB. I am using Arduino UNO and SD Card module to save my db.

Here is my Serial.

[image: Here is my serial]
Here is my table declaration.

```
struct LogEvent {
  int id;
  String fname;
  float temperature;
}
logEvent;

struct SecondEvent {
  int id;
  String lastname;
}
secondEvent;
```

Here is my db.create() code.

```
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(secondEvent));
```

Now, when I try to retrieve, it is a whack. Here is my save and retrieve code.

```
void createRecords(int num_recs, float correctTemperature)
{
    Serial.print("Creating Records... ");
    for (int recno = 1; recno <= num_recs; recno++)
    {
      correctId++;
      logEvent.id = correctId;
      logEvent.fname = "Brix Nicholson";
      logEvent.temperature = correctTemperature;
      secondEvent.id = correctId;    
      EDB_Status result = db.appendRec(EDB_REC logEvent);
      if (result != EDB_OK) printError(result);   
    }
  Serial.println("DONE");
}

void createRecordSecondEvent()
 {
   correctId++;
   secondEvent.id = correctId;
   secondEvent.lastname = "Secretaria";
   EDB_Status result = db.appendRec(EDB_REC secondEvent);
   if (result != EDB_OK) printError(result);
 }  

void selectLastRecord()
{
  int lastRecNum = db.count();
  EDB_Status result = db.readRec(lastRecNum, EDB_REC logEvent);
  if(result == EDB_OK)
   {
     Serial.print(" ID: ");
     Serial.print(logEvent.id);
     Serial.print(" Name: ");
     Serial.print(logEvent.fname);
     Serial.print(" Temp: ");
     Serial.println(logEvent.temperature);
   }
   else printError(result);
}

void selectLastSecondRecord()
{
 int lastRecNum = db.count();
 EDB_Status result = db.readRec(lastRecNum, EDB_REC secondEvent);
 if(result == EDB_OK)
  {
   Serial.print("Second Event ID: ");
   Serial.print(secondEvent.id);
   Serial.print("Last Name: ");
   Serial.print(secondEvent.lastname);
  }
  else printError(result);
}
```

Comment: What's the *trouble*?

Comment: I missed about the address, its all good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer to my problem. I forgot to increase the address of the EDB_header.

I wrote:

```
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(secondEvent));
```

Instead of:

```
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
db.create(1, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(secondEvent));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think I have found the answer to my problem. I forgot to increase
>   the address of the EDB_header.

you're right about increasing the address of EDB_header. 
But the address is the position from where the library starting reading/writing.

if you have a look at 
https://github.com/jwhiddon/EDB/blob/master/EDB.cpp#L66
and 
https://github.com/jwhiddon/EDB/blob/master/EDB.cpp#L34

the library writes a fixed size of the header in the binary format
which includes

1. a magic byte to recognize the EDB header
2. the number of records currently present in the table which is 0 at of this time
3. size of your single record
4. the size of the table (max amount of memory that the table is allowed to consume)

and to write a new record
https://github.com/jwhiddon/EDB/blob/master/EDB.cpp#L93

so in

```
db.create(0, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));
db.create(1, TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(secondEvent));
```

the second statement will override the old header excluding the first byte (0'th position)

the solution to your problem will be

```
unsigned int FIRST_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION = 0;
db.create(FIRST_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION, FIRST_TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(logEvent));

unsigned int SECOND_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION = FIRST_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION + (unsigned int)sizeof(EDB_Header) + FIRST_TABLE_SIZE;

db.create(SECOND_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION, SECOND_TABLE_SIZE, (unsigned int)sizeof(secondEvent));
```

now you can use

```
EDB_Status result = db.open(FIRST_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION );
```

and

```
db.close();
EDB_Status result = db.open(SECOND_TABLE_HEADER_POSITION );
```